# Resources with a defined capacity

Tags: anylogic

I am facing this issue with Anylogic:

I have a resource pool which is my elevator and has a maximum capacity of 5 batches maximum.

the elevator should take
the first batch, look back if there any other, take the second, look back if there are any others, etc.. then 
it should go up. I cannot go up each time I have a pallet inside, and in the same time I cannot wait too much 
till I have all the 5 pallets inside.
Shall I use a queue to do this?
Please help me out as I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: The best way to implement this depends on whether you (a) only want the elevator to go up when there are 5 pallets; (b) wait a max of X seconds (presumably from when it becomes available again) and take all that have arrived in that period (leaving immediately if 5 have arrived). I suspect you want (b).

Comment: Exactly, I need the b scenario. It also could be that the elevator takes only one pallet, but it has to check before if there are any or, as you said, wait a max of a minute before it goes up. Hope it is clear

Answer (score 0):

As usual, many different options, how about this:

Have a "Batch" element that batches your pallets into a new agent type "Elevator-pallets". Then, your ResourcePool seizes those, instead of pallets directly.

Alternatively, use a "Wait" element before your elevator and make a cyclic event empty it into the elevator regularly (`myWaitObject.freeAll()`)

Or do not use a ResourcePool but model the elevator as a direct agent where a state-chart governs the "look and wait, but not too long" in more detail...

...